# Java List to Reactor Flux to Identity Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactor, spring-graphql

I'm trying to implement some simple Spring Boot GraphQL BatchMapping.

The `@BatchMapping` receives a `List<Book>` and then calls a `@Repository` and transforms the result into a `Map<Book, Author>`. I'm struggeling using Reactor's `Flux` and `Mono`.

```java
@BatchMapping
Mono<Map<Book, Author>> author(List<Book> books) {
  List<String> authorIds = books.stream().map(book -> book.authorId).toList();

  Flux<Author> authors = authorRepository.findAllById(authorIds);

  return authors.mapToTheBooksInTheCorrectOrder???();
}
```

Each `Book` has a single `Author`, **but** multiple `Book`s can have the same `Author`.

I'd like to return a `Map` (more precisely a `Mono<Map>`) where the key is *each `Book`* and the value is the corresponding `Author`.

You can assume that the `Author`s within `Flux<Author>` (returned by `authorRepository.findAllById`) are unique, **and** that the returned `Author`s have the same order (first occurence) as the `authorId` from `List<Book>`:

```json
book1 = { id: "1", name: "A Scanner Darkly", authorId = "2" }
book2 = { id: "2", name: "High Fidelity", authorId = "1" }
book3 = { id: "3", name: "The Man In The High Castle", authorId = "2" }
```

will result in:

```json
authors = [
  { id: "2", name: "Philip K. Dick" }
  { id: "1", name: "Nick Hornby" } 
]
```

In other words:

- for each entry in `List<Book>` create a key in the `Map`
- and then get the matching value from the `Flux<Author>`

The result of the method should be (for this example):

```
{
  book1 : author2,
  book2 : author1,
  book3 : author2
}
```

All wrapped within a `Mono<Map>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're struggling with `Flux` and `Mono`, you can use the `collectList()` operator to obtain a `List<Author>`. For example:

```java
return authorRepository
    .findAllById(authorIds)
    .collectList() // Mono<List<Author>>
    .map(authors -> /* Use authors + books to get a Map<Book, Author> */);
```

The benefit of doing so is that you can then use the `map()` operator and work with a `List<Author>` and `List<Book>`, which are types you're probably more familiar with.

Personally, I would even suggest using the `collectMap()` operator and create a `Map` with the ID of the author as the key and the `Author` as the value of the `Map`. This makes it easier to retrieve the relevant `Author` object for each `Book`, because then you can use `authorIdMap.get(book.getAuthorId())`. For example:

```java
return authorRepository
    .findAllById(authorIds)
    .collectMap(Author::getId) // Mono<Map<String, Author>>
    .map(authorIdMap -> /* Use authorIdMap + books to get a Map<Book, Author> */);
```

In this case, `authorIdMap` would be a `Map<String, Author>`.

If you don't want to use a regular for-loop/streams within the `map()` function, you can also use a reactive stream for that. To do so, you first need to make a `Flux<Book>`, and then you can use the `collectMap()` operator a second time, but this time the key will be the `Book` object, and the value will be the corresponding `Author` object.

```java
return authorRepository
    .findAllById(authorIds)
    .collectMap(Author::getId) // Mono<Map<String, Author>>
    .flatMap(authorIdMap -> Flux
        .fromIterable(books) // Flux<Book>
        .collectMap(identity(), book -> authorIdMap.get(book.getAuthorId()))); // Mono<Map<Book, Author>>
```

In this case, you need to use `flatMap()` in stead of `map()` because the function will return a reactive stream in stead of a plain object.

Also, to use the current object as the key within the `collectMap()` operator, you could write `collectMap(book -> book, ...)`. However, a cleaner way of writing these `x -> x` lambdas is by using `Function.identity()` (or `identity()` if you use a static import).